# Can I use Qt quick UI project to develop a real product?

Tags: qml

I am new to Qt Quick development, I am using Qt 5.2. Take a few hours to find a way to create tab view finally.
Below is my code in gui.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

Window {

    width: 538 + frame.margins * 2
    height: 360 + frame.margins * 2

    ToolBar {
        id: toolbar
        width: parent.width
    }

    SystemPalette {id: syspal}
    color: syspal.window


    Rectangle {
        anchors.top: toolbar.bottom
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.bottom:  parent.bottom
        anchors.margins: 8

        TabView {
            id:frame
            focus:true

            property int margins: Qt.platform.os === "osx" ? 16 : 0

            height: parent.height - 34
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.margins: margins

            Tab {
                title: "Home"
            }
            Tab {
                title: "Edit"
            }
            Tab {
                title: "View"
            }

            Tab {
                title: "Help"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Qt Creator to create a qt quick ui project, it only has two files, one is gui.qml, another one is gui.qmlproject. Can I use it as a real product project? If it is, how to add my C++ code, e.g. replace the default windows title "QtQmlViewer" with my product name when the main windows pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need another another type of project: `QtQuick 2 Application (Built-in elements)`. [This](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-deployment.html) article can be helpful. Also, QtQuick Controls can require another startup file. Try [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/qqmlapplicationengine.html#details) if your app will not be able to load QML file

Comment: You are right. QQmlApplictionEngine is the key class which loads qml in runtime. But the official doc does not give useful example, I find the code in examples:


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    if ( !window ) {
        qWarning("Error: Your root item has to be a Window.");
        return -1;
    }
    window->show();